# Revoke Google Access Token in PHP

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

As the title reads, I want to revoke a granted access token programatically (in PHP that is). I found this on [their website](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke), but can't seem to find a function in the [api client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). Is there a clean library function?

**EDIT:**
As pointed out by [DaimTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto) there is a function called revokeToken(). So this code works in PHP (with composer):

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(GOOGLE_APP_NAME);
$client->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->revokeToken($access_token);
```

Comment: Have you tried something like $client->revokeToken($token) ?

Comment: No, because I could not find it. Do both tokens have to be revoked (refresh + access) ?

Comment: try  $client->revokeToken();   (I am digging in the lib now :)  https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=revokeToken)  other wise I think it accepts an $accesstoken

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for me. Can I accept the comment as the correct answer?

Comment: nope but I can post it as an answer and you can accept that.  I am glad you got it working I need to note this for future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
$client->revokeToken();
```

or

```
$client->revokeToken($accesstoken);
```

Information found by digging around the [Google-api-php-Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=revokeToken)

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
/** logout file **/
<?php    
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';    
session_start();    
$accesstoken=$_SESSION['access_token'];

//Unset token and user data from session    
unset($_SESSION['access_token']);    
unset($_SESSION['userData']);    

//Reset OAuth access token    
$client = new Google_Client();

//$client->revokeToken();    
$client->revokeToken($accesstoken);

//Destroy entire session    
session_destroy();    

//Redirect to homepage    
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/googlelogin/index.php';    
header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));    
?>
```

Comment: a day saver, works without intervention (beside the redirect_uri ofcourse, but that makes sense