# How to revoke Google user access oauth login

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, google-api-php-client

I have found for facebook: DELETE /{user_id}/permissions
But not found like above for Google
 I am using following Laravel package https://github.com/oriceon/oauth-5-laravel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server side removal of Oauth token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087240/server-side-removal-of-oauth-token)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Revoke Google Access Token in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515231/revoke-google-access-token-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to revoke the oauth token

$client->revokeToken();

check the documentation when using oauth2 this might help you
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: I have used the HTTP\REST call